# IE 11 prints blank page when using window.open (IE bug) -

Tags: javascript, window.open

Can someone please throw some light on this weird IE bug, Trying to print only selected section works fine across all browser but IE 11. IE open blank page I don't see any error either. Spent several hours on this researching and trying different work arounds.

```
   events:{
        'click td.delete-cell .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove': 'removeRow',

        'click th.delete-cell .glyphicon.glyphicon-remove': 'removeAll',

        'click .print-button': 'printClicked'
    },

    printClicked: function() {
        var printHTML = $("<div></div>"), summaryTable, driverInfo, driverId;
        // If there is no Print Window open, or it was closed
        if ( !this.printWindow || !this.printWindow.window ) {
          this.printWindow = window.open('', this.options.device.attributes.displayName + " Parameters Report");

            $(this.printWindow.document.head).append(this.getTemplate(this.PrintCSSTemplate)());
            $(this.printWindow.document.body).addClass('PRINTMODE');

            driverId = this.device.get('driverId') ? parseInt(this.device.get('driverId'), 10) : null;
            driverInfo = this.drivers.findWhere({ driverId: driverId });

            printHTML.append(
                this.getTemplate(this.PrintSummaryDeviceOverviewTemplate)(_.extend({},
                    this.options.device.toJSON(),
                    { driver: driverInfo.toJSON() }
                ))
            );

            summaryTable = this.$('table').clone();
            summaryTable.find('.delete-cell').remove();
            summaryTable.appendTo(printHTML);

            printHTML.appendTo(this.printWindow.document.body);

            this.printWindow.print();

        }
    },
```

Comment: im guessing that its a cross origin issue. opening `''` (empty string) might be interpreted as a different origin

Comment: Why don't you use css's `@media print` and create two classes `.no-print { display: none; }` and `.print { display: block; }`. Assign the classes accordingly to your section. Open print preview and you should only see the sections marked with `.print`...

Comment: The FIX is jQuery was unable to append an in-memory DOM element to the bare document.body, and only in IE
printHTML.appendTo(this.printWindow.document.body);
The fix comes in two parts:
Wrapping the document body object 
Appending printHTML contents as string (gross, I know)
The final flow is:

var $body = $(this.printWindow.document.body);
// populate `printHTML`
$body.append(printHTML.html());

Comment: @parnan Glad you worked it out. To make it clearer for others with the same problem in future, you should post your fix as an answer and mark it as the accepted answer (even tho you are answering your own question)